# Jquery-Ajax: Open fancybox via submit a second time results in $.fancybox undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I use the following script to catch the click on a second submit-button and send the data via ajax to fancybox. The script works fine, but only the first time. If you close fancybox and want to open it again, the firefox-console says that `$.fancybox` is undefined and nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(':submit').click(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr('id');
            if (value == 'preview') {
                $.fancybox.showLoading();
                $.ajax({
                    type    : 'POST',
                    cache   : false,
                    url     : '/mypath/index.php',
                    data    : $('#myform').serializeArray(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        $.fancybox(data)

                        }
                    });
                    return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Maybe it has to do with the other scripts used on the site: These are Datepicker, Bassistance Validate and Tooltip and some custom-scripts. I created a small demopage just with a form and a small destination `/mypath/test.php` and had no problems.

**Edit**: Deleted, no good idea. If the problem would have been caused by the .ready it wouldn't work on the testpage.

**Edit2**: Solved. The problem was, that I called jquery and the ui in the header of the target-site `url       : '/mypath/index.php'`. I deleted the code and now it runs!

Comment: You'll get this error if you include the fancybox.js file before jquery file

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem in this case. The fancybox.js file is positioned AFTER the jquery file. And it works the first time, when you hit the button, it only doesn't work if you hit the button a second time.

If the fancybox.js file is positoned BEFORE the jquery file, fancybox doesn't work a bit.

Comment: Firebug will show you proper errors which will help you (and us!) solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe I don't know how to use fb, but it doesn't tell me more than `TypeError: $.fancybox is undefined
$.fancybox.showLoading();`